# why cannot I initialize char** c with c = new (char*)[10], while c = new char*[10] is ok?

Tags: c++, pointers

why cannot I initialize `char** c` with：

```
 c = new (char*)[10];
```

, while：

```
 c = new char*[10];
```

is ok?

Comment: `new (char *)[10]` is not valid syntax.  What are you wanting to do?

Comment: why not? int* i = new int[10]; is valid. Why can't I replace int with char* while adding '( )' to say that the type of the array is "char *"? @VaughnCato

Comment: I've added an answer to try to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit strange. The [new-statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) has two formats, either

```
new (optional_parameters) ( type ) optional_initializer
```

or

```
new (optional_parameters) type optional_initializer
```

Your attempt with `new (char*)[10]` does not fit the first form, even though `(char*)`looks like `(type)`, because `[10]` isn't a valid initializer.

Your other attempt does fit the second form with `type` being `char*[10]` and both optional parts missing.

Comment: int* i = new int[10]; is valid. Why can't I replace int with char* while adding '( )' to say that the type of the array is "char *"?

Comment: The type isn't `char*` but `char*[10]`. The size of an array is part of the type.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons that are beyond the scope of this answer, the designers of the language decided that:

```
new (char*)[10]
```

is not a syntactically valid expression. Since that is not a syntactically valid expression, it does not make sense to initialize `char** c` with

```
c = new (char*)[10];
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no. We can discuss pointless decisions, but that doesn't explain anything, nor does it change the facts.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You got exactly that in this answer.

Comment: @ThePara Not as far as I can see.

Comment: Of course, somehow my original comment was removed which makes this discussion pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The type used for `new` expressions works similarly to how variable declarations work, but with the variable name removed.  To declare an array of 10 character pointers, you use

```
char *p[10];
```

not

```
(char *) p[10];
```

Likewise, to dynamically allocate an array of 10 character pointers, you use

```
new char *[10]
```

not

```
new (char *)[10]
```